# Capitalising Extended-Latin multibyte characters in PHP and outputting them as escaped HTML

Tags: php, html, utf-8, internationalization, escaping

I've stumbled across a problem in PHP and it's proving *much* harder to solve than I would have expected.

On the English version of my site, I have a plaintext-fragment:

```
about-us
```

which I can straightforwardly change into the capitalised text form:

```
About Us
```

using the following:

```
$Text_Array = explode('-', $Plain_Text_Fragment); // ['about', 'us']

for ($i = 0; $i < count($Text_Array); $i++) {
  $Text_Array[$i] = strtoupper($Text_Array[$i][0]) . substr($Text_Array[$i], 1);
}

$Capitalised_Text = implode(' ', $Text_Array); // 'About Us'
```

---

It turns out, it's *not nearly so straightforward* to turn the plaintext fragment:

```
über-uns
```

into the capitalised text form:

```
&Uuml;ber Uns
```

**TLDR:** *What's the most straightforward approach in PHP to achieve this?*

---

### Problem #1 : Ascertaining whether the first letter is multi-byte

I only need to capitalise the first letter of each word in the plaintext-fragment, so, whilst I can easily tell that the plaintext-fragment contains one or more multibyte characters, using:

```
strlen('über') === mb_strlen('über') // FALSE
```

that still doesn't tell me whether the **first letter** of the plaintext fragment is multibyte or not. (It might be one or more of any of the other letters).

I can't isolate and test `$Text_Array[$i][0]` because, of course, the `'ü'` in `'über'` is both `$Text_Array[$i][0]` *and* `$Text_Array[$i][1]`.

It also appears that `mb_str_split()` does not exist.

---

### Problem #2 : Capitalising `'ü'`

Once I am past *Problem #1* (having confirmed that the first letter of `'über'` is multibyte), it's not clear to me how to capitalise it. I want to use `mb_strtoupper()` but I need to use this on both `$Text_Array[$i][0]` *and* `$Text_Array[$i][1]` and no other character (unless there are other multibyte characters in `$Text_Array[$i]`.

I think I can solve **Problem #2** something like this:

```
$Text_Array[$i] = mb_strtoupper(substr($Text_Array[$i], 0, 2)) . substr($Text_Array[$i], 2);
```

**I have checked this and it definitely works. One down, two to go.**

---

### Problem #3 : Outputting `&Uuml;` instead of `Ü`

Although I am working using UTF-8 encoding, I'd much prefer to output the HTML-escape `&Uuml;` than a raw `Ü`. I figured there would be a PHP native function to allow me to convert between the two and there is:

```
htmlentities()
```

But I really can't tell if `htmlentities()` is working or not because both my **DOM Inspector** and my **View Source** are telling me that they see `Ü`, not `&Uuml;`. I appreciate that they might be seeing the latter and *they are just trying to be helpful*, but I can't be absolutely sure whether the PHP function `htmlentities()` is working or not.

---

### Question:

What's the most straightforward approach in PHP to convert:

```
über-uns
```

into:

```
&Uuml;ber Uns ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `mb_convert_case`

```php
$string = "über-uns";

$string = str_replace("-", " ", $string);

$capitalised = mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");

echo htmlentities($capitalised, ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This is much better solution to the task itself than my answer which explains how to do it like the OP initially attempted.

Comment: Superb, @András, thank you very much. I've never encountered `mb_convert_case()` before and it looks very useful. In the course of reading more about it, I also discovered [`ucfirst()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) and [`ucwords()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php). This has been an education!

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close there, but stick to mb_* functions all the way:

```
$Text_Array = explode('-', $Plain_Text_Fragment); // ['about', 'us']

for ($i = 0; $i < count($Text_Array); $i++) {
    $Text_Array[$i] = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($Text_Array[$i],0,1)) . mb_substr($Text_Array[$i], 1);
}

$Capitalised_Text = implode(' ', $Text_Array); // 'About Us'
```

#### Problem 1: Use `mb_substr()`

Use `mb_substr` to access the first character. Square bracket will access the first byte, not multibyte codepoint.

#### Problem 2: Use `mb_strtoupper()`

This is not an issue once you get the first multibyte character, just stick to `mb_strtoupper` and you are fine.

#### Problem 3: Specify charset for `htmlentities()`

This is sorted out by specifying the charset for `htmlentities`, e.g:

```
htmlentities($Capitalised_Text,null,'UTF-8')
```

Of course if your [default_charset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) is set to UTF-8 you may skip this and use `htmlentities()` directly.

Comment: Thanks, @vhu. This was very helpful. I wasn't previously aware that it's recommended practice to include the optional encoding argument when using `htmlentities()`. Nor, given my unfamiliarity to date with `mb_` functions, did I realise that there exists an `mb_substr` function - that's very useful to know. Thank you, again.